# Story ID - US vs Chinese vs Aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, hard-sci-fi

I'm trying to remember a book series. It was published in last 5-10 years. Features the US and the Chinese at war in space, trying to make use of an artifact found on a planet that's a map of some sort. The Americans have a force of soldiers who inhabit combat avatars. Ring a bell for anybody?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: Your title mentions aliens. Nothing about aliens in your question. What about the aliens? Where do they come in, what are they like, whose side are they on?

Comment: Good point 14. The aliens are against all human factions, and live in a zone of chaos beyond the rift, or something cliche like that.

Comment: Good. Is there anything else you can remember about the books that you haven't told us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if this is the book [Hammered](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?156889) by Elizabeth Bear, the first book in [the Jenny Casey trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/51463-jenny-casey). It matches some parts of your description, though not all and it was published in 2005 so it's at the extreme edge of your time frame.

Jenny Casey is an ex soldier recruited into a secret mission. The mission turns out to be the study of an alien ship, as in your description, though I don't recall it containing a map. There are two more derelict alien ships on Mars, though I forget what part they play in the story

The US is in conflict with the Chinese, in particular for possession of the ship and the secrets it holds.

I don't recall avatar combat suits, but avatars are used and there is an avatar pilot training school that features at one point. There is also something called the Avatar Gamespace.

It's one of those books with multiple subplots and I honestly can't remember thm all. However there is an AI that calls itself Richard Feynman and part of the plot concerns the AI's attempts to escape into the global network.

As I recall the book ends with the US having built a starship using the technology from the alien craft. It ends with the implication that the aliens are out there and aren't friendly.